# Get rid of gray line in R density plot density at y = 0

Tags: r, plot, postscript, eps, density-plot

I have a density plot that I want to save in an eps file.

My density plot is something like

```
setEPS()
postscript("myfile.eps")
plot(density(rnorm(1000)))
dev.off()
```

just with my data and a little bit more complex (changing labels and margins, more lines on top of it, etc).

My problem is that I get an annoying, horizontal thin gray line on top of my density plot at y = 0, and I'd like to get rid of it.

When plotting directly to the X device I don't get this horizontal gray line, but in postscript I always do.

I've tried using `dev.copy2eps` and also `cairo_ps()` instead of `postscript()`, but I still get the grey line.

I've also tried using different (and random) data, with a very simple plot like the code block above, and still get the grey line in the postscript.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this line?

Comment: Nothing to do with postscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the help page:

```
?plot.density
```

zero.line.......logical; if TRUE, add a base line at y = 0

I will admit that I didn't discover this by reading the help page. I had looked at the code for `density.default`, found nothing useful, then tried `plot.density`, got the nothing, found message, and then tried:

```
> getAnywhere(plot.density)
```

Which produced this  ... making me realize that *I* should have started with the help page:

```
A single object matching ‘plot.density’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for plot from namespace stats
  namespace:stats
with value

function (x, main = NULL, xlab = NULL, ylab = "Density", type = "l", 
    zero.line = TRUE, ...)
```

Comment: It might be fatigue, but I actually looked at that help file and just didn't see that. Thanks a lot! :)